# 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found

Tags: c#, linq, selectlist

I've got the following code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebShopGoal.Models;

namespace WebShopGoal.ViewModel
{
    public class ProductEditViewModel 
    {
        public Products Product { get; set; }
        public SelectList SupplierIdList { get; set; }
        public MultiSelectList CategoryIdList { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedCategories { get; set; }
        public int? SupplierId { get; set; }

        private WebshopDBEntities _db; 

        public ProductEditViewModel()
        {
            _db = new WebshopDBEntities();

            SupplierIdList = new SelectList(_db.Suppliers, "Id", "Name");
            CategoryIdList = new MultiSelectList(_db.Categories, "Id", "CName");
        }

        public void Load(int id)
        {
            Product = _db.Products.Find(id);

            SupplierId = Product.SupplierId;
            SelectedCategories = Product.CategoryId.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();    
        }
```

and in the last bit, on the select it gives an error. I use the same code in a diffrent ViewModel but it is working in that one. 
In my view i Use

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Categories, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCategories, Model.CategoryIdList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me? Some searching here says using System.Linq will solve it but  i already got that one

Comment: You can use Linq only on types derived from `IEnumerable`. But it seems like `Product.CategoryId` is of type int. I'm not sure what you try to achieve here.

Comment: Can you share your `Product` class?

Comment: can you post your Products class?

Comment: Looks to me like you want this `SelectedCategories = new int[] { Product.CategoryId };`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Price] [float] NOT NULL,
 [Tax] [int] NOT NULL,
 [SupplierId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL, ------ CaregoryId is indeed int, no wonder it is not working

Comment: @Rubiqs perhaps you should explain what are you trying to do with that Select.  In other words what are you trying to show in your ListBox

Comment: I want a listbox with all the available categories so i can assign some catagories to one product.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're trying to do here is:

```
SelectedCategories = new int[] { Product.CategoryId };
```

Comment: He wants category id not product id.

Comment: Indeed he does; fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you want this:

```
SelectedCategories = new int[] { Product.CategoryId };
```